# Checking for specific data in every JSON key

Tags: javascript

"testDB" is a json file that contains data like this

```
{
  "003": {
    "ID": "003",
    "userID": "65489787984651423"
  },
  "004": {
    "ID": 004
    "userID": "73453212502130754"
  }
}
```

How do I check if an userID is in any of the keys' userID value?
I tried this

```
for (let i in testDB) {
    if ("73453212502130754" === testDB[i].userID) return console.log(testDB[i].ID)
}
console.log("none")
```

however it doesn't seem to do what it was supposed to do in the for loop when the userID 73453212502130754 is in the JSON database, Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're both logging the ID if it's found, and also "none". So ideally you want to actually store the ID in a variable, and then either log that once the loop is done, *or* "none".

```js
const testDB={"003":{ID:"003",userID:"65489787984651423"},"004":{ID:"004",userID:"73453212502130754"}};

let found;

for (let key in testDB) {
  if ('73453212502130754' === testDB[key].userID) {
    found = testDB[key].ID;
  }
}

console.log(found || 'none');
```

You could also create a utility function where you can pass in your data, the property you want to search for, its value, and the value of the property you want to return.

```js
const testDB={"003":{ID:"003",userID:"65489787984651423"},"004":{ID:"004",userID:"73453212502130754"}};

function findData(data, prop, value, returnValue) {

  // Get the values of the object (an array) and loop over the
  // objects to find where the object property matches the value
  const result = Object.values(data).find(obj => obj[prop] === value);

  // If `result` exists, return the required value, or "none"
  return result ? result[returnValue] : 'none';
}

const result = findData(testDB, 'userID', '73453212502130754', 'ID');
console.log(result);

const result1 = findData(testDB, 'ID', '004', 'userID');
console.log(result1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think your code is just formatted incorrectly, please try this:

```
for(let i in testDB){
    if("73453212502130754" == testDB[i].userID){
        return console.log(testDB[i].ID)
    }else{
        console.log("none")
    }
```

Comment: This would log "none" for each object in the loop that doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

The following will filter out the object in question:

```js
const d={
  "003": {
"ID": "003",
"userID": "65489787984651423"
  },
  "004": {
"ID": "004",
"userID": "73453212502130754"
  }
};

const res=Object.values(d).filter(e=>e.userID==="73453212502130754");

console.log(res.length? res[0].ID : "not found!");
```